# How can i get precision up-to 128 decimal places in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I have tried BigInteger, decimal, float and long but no luck.
[Screenshot of required output example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maulV.png)

Comment: Can you explain why you need that much precision?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by that much precision? Why 128? And why "128 decimal places"? Why not 129 decimal places or 113?

Comment: I am working on an algorithm to simulate network evolution. I need a minimum of 128 decimal places to calculate precise probabilities of events between different time steps.

Comment: Is there any way I can get this from built-in data types? or what should I do to extend default functionalities?

Comment: Create class using BigInt with a exponent property that contains the location of the decimal point.  A floating point number can always be represented as a whole number and an exponent.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, if any of the answers to this question prove useful to you. Please upvote them and accept the most useful. If they aren't any help, or if you need further clarification on something, just add a comment and the answerer will likely be happy to help!

Comment: @Riz - Yes, but why 128? Every decimal place has an order of magnitude less importance on the value. The 128th decimal place is `10^128` less important that the "zeroth" decimal place. That's a very very very big number. So why 128?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve arbitrary precision numbers is to combine the `BigInteger` class from `System.Numerics` with an `int` exponent. You could use `BigInteger` for your exponent, but this is likely overkill as the numbers would be well beyong meaningful in scale.

So if you create a class along these lines:

```
public class ArbDecimal
{
    BigInteger value;
    int exponent;
    public override string ToString()
    {
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
         int place;
         foreach (char digit in value.ToString())
         {
             if (place++ == value.ToString().Length - exponent)
             {
                 sb.Append('.');
             }
             sb.Append(digit);
         }
         return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

You should then be able to define your mathematical operations using the laws of indices with the `value` and `exponent` fields.

For instance, to achieve addition, you would scale the larger value to have the same exponent as the smaller one by multiplying it by `10^(largerExp-smallerExp)` then adding the two values and rescaling.

---

In your class, the number `0.01` would be represented like:

```
value = 1

exponent = -2
```

Due to the fact that `1*10^-2 = 0.01`.

---

Utilising this method, you can store arbitrarily precise (and large) numbers limited only by the available ram and the `.NET` framework's object size limit.

Comment: Math.Pow(value,exponent) is not correct, has to be value * magic.Pow(10, exponent).  Please add magic.

Comment: My mistake, it's actualy `BigInteger.Pow(x,y)` in this case. It's just habit to use Math.Pow

Comment: BigInteger.Pow takes an int.

Comment: And this is why I shouldn't answer questions without access to VS to test them. Cheers @EricLippert, fixed it now

Comment: Wrong magic, think a bit more about how you are going to produce "3.1428...." from that expression.  Keep in mind that you are only moving the position of the decimal point.

Comment: Like so: `31428 * 10^-4`? What's this magic thing you're talking about? Fair enough this method isn't going to handle irrational or transcendental numbers, but that's not relevant in this case.

Comment: I note that this is exactly how `decimal` works in C#; a decimal stores a 96 bit integer, an exponent that can go from 0 to 28, and some flags.

Comment: That's interesting @EricLippert, didn't know that. Thanks :)

Comment: It is a good suggestion then we also need to write functions for arithmetic operations. But how would it represent mantissa correctly? I need all the significant digits up to 128 places.

Comment: @Riz: The mantissa is the big integer. Write functions for the arithmetic operations by **writing functions**. You're a computer programmer; program a computer!

Comment: @Riz you would store all of the 128 places in the `value` method and then the exponent just controls where the decimal point goes

Comment: I think Hans Passant's point is that BigInteger.Pow returns a BigInteger. It cannot be used to print out a fraction. What you need to do is turn the mantissa to a string, and then insert the decimal point at the correct place.

Comment: Thanks @james-hughes

Comment: @EricLippert ahh so it would... I'll just go and fix that now.

Comment: @Riz, no worries.

Answer (score 4):

It is a fairly easy task to write your own rational class; remember, rationals are just pairs of integers, and you already have BigInteger.

In this series of articles I show how to devise your own big integer and big rational classes starting from absolutely nothing, *not even integers*. Note that this is not fast and not intended to be fast; it is intended to be educational. You can use the techniques I describe in this series to help you when designing your arithmetic class.

https://ericlippert.com/2013/09/16/math-from-scratch-part-one/

Or, if you don't want to write it yourself, you can always use the one from Microsoft:

http://bcl.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BigRational&referringTitle=Home

But that said...

> I need a minimum of 128 decimal places to calculate precise probabilities of events between different time steps

Do you need 128 decimal places to represent 128 digits of *precision*, or of *magnitude*? Because if it is just magnitude, then simply do a transformation of your probability math into logarithms and do the math in doubles.

Comment: `BigRational` looks good, I didn't even know it existed. Wonder why it's not included in `System.Numerics`